# Facebook Send Request returns Error

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm try to popup dialog with pre-specified addressee that way:

```
FB.init({
  appId      : 'MYAPPID',
  status     : true,
  cookie     : true, 
  xfbml      : true,  
  frictionlessRequests: true
}); 

function sendRequestToRecipients() 
{
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'You have just received a PP request.',
      to: '100000526845569'
    }, requestCallback);
}

sendRequestToRecipineds();
```

When the popup opens I've the error: `An error occurred. Please try later`

When I look at the request URL of the popup I see the following:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?message=You%20have%20just%20received%20a%20PP%20request.&to=100000526845569&api_key=&app_id=&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&display=popup&frictionless=false&next=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D18%23cb%3Df23f09878cdaf1e%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmyhost.com%252Ff1868d80900b7a%26domain%3Dmyhost.com%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df27cb35acbd146c%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522

I think some info has not been sent: 
`api_key, app_id`

How come? Any ideas?

Login with facebook works perfectly. Multifriend selector too.

---

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 // init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
  appId      : 'MYAPPID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
  channelUrl : '//mydomain.com/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
  status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
  cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
  xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
  frictionlessRequests: true
});


};

 // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously

 (function(d, debug){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document, /*debug*/ false));

function sendRequestToRecipients() {

    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'You have just received a PP request.',
      to: '100000143396036'
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request'
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function requestCallback(response) {
    // Handle callback here
  }

 </script>
```

That's how its made here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the javascript SDK asynchronously before calling `FB.init()` (if you have not) like this:

```
<script>

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
  {
    FB.init({
      appId      : APP_ID,
      status     : true, 
      cookie     : true, 
      xfbml      : true,  
      frictionlessRequests: true
    });
    //Additional Code here
  };        

 // Load the SDK Asynchronously
 (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }
 (document));

</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it is exactly how its done in my script.. The problem is hidden somewhere else.. :(

Comment: I think above script you call `FB.init` function before loading SDK js.

Answer (score 1):

FIXED.

Strange, but the PRESENCE of ASYNC SDK messed it all.

Thank you